# will the jews be rewarded heaven for following their messiah (the anti christ)?

Tags: jews, dajjal

since we know that the dajjal will have 70 thousand followers of jews from iran or something like that 
which they think he is their messiah which he is our anti christ
the question is will they be rewarded by allah for following him
or are they commanded to stay away for him and wait for isa peace upon him and mahdi like muslims and christians?

Comment: What is your evidence that the messiah of the Jews is the anti Christ? And what is the relevance of this question with the topic of our site the teaching of Islam?

Answer (score 2):

No one would enter paradise unless they died on Islam, believing in all its requirements including in Muhammad ﷺ and the Quran.

> ومن يبتغ غير الإسلام دينا فلن يقبل منه وهو في الآخرة من الخاسرين
>
> And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:85](https://quran.com/3/85)</sup>

> لا يسمع بي أحد من هذه الأمة يهودي ولا نصراني ثم لم يؤمن بالذي أرسلت به إلا كان من أصحاب النار
>
> Whoever amongst the community of Jews or Christians hears about me, but does not affirm his belief in that with which I have been sent and dies in this state, he shall be but one of the denizens of Hell-Fire.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/293)</sup>

The Dajjal is not the messiah of the Jews, Isa عليه السلام  is the messiah.

> المسيح عيسى ابن مريم وجيها في الدنيا والآخرة ومن المقربين
>
> The Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary - distinguished in this world and the Hereafter and among those brought near [to Allah]
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:45](http://quran.com/3/45)</sup>

And the Dajjal has been warned against:

> وما من نبي إلا أنذره قومه
>
> there was no prophet but warned his nation against him
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/12) & [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/54/127)</sup>

The Dajjal would be a an impostor, who would falsely claim to be a prophet, messiah and eventually claim to be God. It is rather absurd to think that someone has been commanded to and will be rewarded for doing *shirk* and *kufr*.